# Use shinyjs and ggplot2::autoplot in the same shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyjs

I use the function `ggplot2::autoplot` with a `lm` object on my shiny app.
This is possible thanks to the package `ggfortify`.

On my shiny app I also use `shinyjs`.
On the reproductible example below, as soon as I uncomment `library(shinyjs)` & `useShinyjs()` I get the error :
`Error in unclass(x) : cannot unclass an environment`.

Any idea on a possible workaround ?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
#library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    #useShinyjs(),
    div(
        actionButton("run", "Run")
        ,uiOutput("ui_autoplot")
    )   
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    data <- iris

    rv_autoplot <- eventReactive(input$run, {
        a <- lm(data = data, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length)
        p <- autoplot(a, which = 1:6, label.size = 2, data = data)
        return(p)
    })

    output$autoplot <- renderPlot({
        req(rv_autoplot())
        rv_autoplot()
    })


    output$ui_autoplot <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("autoplot")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyjs_0.9.1   bindrcpp_0.2    ggfortify_0.4.1 ggplot2_2.2.1   shiny_1.0.5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     magrittr_1.5     bindr_0.1        munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 xtable_1.8-2     R6_2.2.2        
 [8] rlang_0.1.2      plyr_1.8.4       dplyr_0.7.4      tools_3.4.1      grid_3.4.1       gtable_0.2.0     miniUI_0.1.1    
[15] htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.1.14      lazyeval_0.2.0   digest_0.6.12    assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_1.3.4     gridExtra_2.3   
[22] tidyr_0.6.3      glue_1.1.1       mime_0.5         labeling_0.3     compiler_3.4.1   scales_0.5.0     jsonlite_1.5    
[29] httpuv_1.3.5     pkgconfig_2.0.1  Cairo_1.5-9
```

Comment: On my machine, it won't work even with shinyJS commented out.

Comment: As soon as shinyjs is loaded, it doesn't work anymore. Maybe `detach("package:shinyjs", unload = TRUE)`. If persist, which error do you get ?

Comment: You're right. Embarassing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the masked functions that appear once you load `shinyjs`

> The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
>
> removeClass, show

Namely, the function `show`.

Your can solve that problem by either doing what **SBista** did in her answer or *remask* the function in your global environment, by adding this

```
show <- methods::show
```

right after you load the libraries.

Comment: I added this line after `library(shinyjs)`but still get the error

Comment: @qfazille This is strange then. As in _I dont believe it_. Sorry.

Comment: My bad, I had to set it in the server part and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is an oversight I had when originally developing shinyjs (also because I never thought it would get popular) - I'm sorry this is causing issues. FYI if you want to still use `show()` and `removeClass()` from shinyjs, you can use their synonyms `showElement()` and `removeCssClass()`

Answer (score 4):

You could call the `shinyjs` argument using namespace instead of loading the library, `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you have an explanation on that strange behavior ?

Comment: This behavior is due the masked function as suggested by **K.Rhode** in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'll switch the accepted answer to K.Rohde's because his solution prevent to prefix every shinyjs function by `shinyjs::`.

Comment: @qfazille I agree! His answer is more elegant and is a better solution.